# how do i have quotes inside of a echo?

Tags: json, linux, shell, ubuntu, echo

I need some help.
I am trying to do something like this

```
echo "{
    "server":"$SERVER_HOST",
    "server_port":"$SERVER_PORT",
    "password":"$PASSWORD_CHOICE",
    "timeout":$TIMEOUT_CHOICE
}" >> /etc/ss/example.json
```

and i need the output like

```
{
    "server":"127.0.0.1",
    "server_port":80,
    "password":"randompassword",
    "timeout":60
}
```

but the output is always like

```
{
    server:127.0.0.1,
    server_port:80,
    password:randompassword,
    timeout:60
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `echo`, but `cat` with a here-document:

```
cat >> /etc/ss/example.json <<EOF
{
  "server":"$SERVER_HOST",
  "server_port":"$SERVER_PORT",
  "password":"$PASSWORD_CHOICE",
  "timeout":$TIMEOUT_CHOICE
}
EOF
```

Answer (score 1):

use backslash to put special characters like `\"` or `\n` for nextline or `\t` for tab

```sh
echo "this is my quotes -> \" <-"
```

the out put will be

```
this is my quotes -> " <-
```

Answer (score 0):

you have two approaches:

- The first, already answered in other responses, is to use the other quotes (if you have used `'`, then use `"`, or viceversa)  but you normally lose the possibility of interpreting shell variables, if you use `'` externally.
- The second, is to get out of quotes, and use escape `\\` character to escape the shell interpretation, as in
- The approach commented in some responses, of using the escape character *inside* quotes, normally gives not good results (depending on the used shell, escapes don't work inside single quotes, or even inside double quotes)  The best is to exit from quotes, escape, and get in quotes again, as shown below.
- The approach of using `cat(1)` and in-flow redirecting input with `<<` is shell dependant (not all shells allow this, so you have to be carefull)

```
echo "{
    "\""server"\"":"\""$SERVER_HOST"\"",
    "\""server_port"\"":"\""$SERVER_PORT"\"",
    "\""password"\"":"\""$PASSWORD_CHOICE"\"",
    "\""timeout"\"":$TIMEOUT_CHOICE
}" >> /etc/ss/example.json
```

you have just to convert each `"` inside the string into `"\""` (if you have used double quotes to quote your string).   The same also works for single quotes (in case you have used single quotes to quote your string), converting each `'` into `'\''`.

Comment: A+ Amazing, Please more